# Careers Job search near Netherland says 0 jobs near Cookeville, TN

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I was wondering why searching a job near "netherland" used in the search field gives as a result "0 jobs near Cookeville, TN"

Cookeville doesn't look too near to Netherland to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue probably is that it's called ["(The) Netherlands"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands) and not "Netherland" in English. **And** there's a Netherland Road in Cookeville, TN.

[Searching for "Netherlands"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=netherlands) returns 10 job listings, including Amsterdam and Delft. The same applies to [searching for "Holland"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=holland) as well as [searching for "Nederland"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=Nederland) (which is the local name).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but there is something weird nevertheless. In fact, if I search "The Netherlands" it still finds Cookeville. If you look at your screenshot it says "10 jobs in Netherlands" it doesn't say "The" or Nederland.

Comment: Hmm... *> if I search "The Netherlands" it still finds Cookeville* — no, the "The" is stripped out and I get [the same results](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=the+netherlands). Note that you always get "Netherlands" in the results, regardless of what you're searching for (e.g. "The Netherlands", "Nederland", ...)