# Careers. Searching for 'Near Auckland' give '0 jobs near Orosi, CA'

Tags: support, jobs

like this one: [Careers Job search near Netherland says 0 jobs near Cookeville, TN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103856/careers-job-search-near-netherland-says-0-jobs-near-cookeville-tn)

Does this mean that stack exchange uses a soundex type search? Not that it sounds the same to my thinking.

I don't mind it finding Auckland in China, or the US or whereever - that's my problem. I just wonder why Orisi is mentioned. Surely just putting Auckland in will hone in an Auckland, doesn't matter which on.

Comment: I find it odd that people put in an unqualified place name and expect these things to find the right one - place names are often not unique and it's hardly surprising that by default Careers.SO searches in the USA. What happens if you search for "Auckland, New Zealand"? (assuming you mean *that* Auckland, of course, because there are [a few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_%28disambiguation%29), including one in California - as per the Careers location match)

Comment: @dma57361 - thank you. I've edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: In this context CA isn't China, it's California (USA). And from web searching it seems that Auckland, California is really tiny or something of that nature. [Orosi, California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orosi,_California) is listed as a "census-designated place" (whatever that is), so I presume it is the nearest matchable "land division" to Auckland, California, hence why it is returned. As another example, if I search for one of the tiny villages near to me I get "0 jobs near <big town>, England" - I think you're experiencing the same effect.

Comment: I know CA is that place Lex Luthor tried to sink and not in China. However why would the search even bother with tell me that? It's not what asked. If place x is near place y then techincally place z near x but directly away from y could be outside the 'near y'.

Comment: Presumably it's just an implementation detail in how they match up jobs to locations - but we'd have to see if a team member chimes in. And I don't think it's particularly alarming that they do this by dropping the smaller and less significant locations - to anyone actually searching for a job in Auckland, CA (or any other less significant location) I suspect they would know what and where Orosi, CA (or their nearest significant town / region) was and not be surprised.

Answer (score 5):

We are at the mercy of Yahoo's GeoData lookup service here. The more specific you can be about where you mean, the better it's able to find what you're looking for.  Searching for "Auckland, NZ" or "Auckland, New Zealand" gives the correct location.

Comment: That's fair enough..

Answer (score 4):

In this context CA isn't China, it's California (USA).

And from web searching it seems that Auckland, California is really tiny (or something of that nature).

However, [Orosi, California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orosi,_California) is apparently a "census-designated place" (whatever that is), so I presume it is the nearest matchable "land division" to Auckland, California, hence why it is returned.

As an alternative example, if I search for some of the tiny villages near to me I get
`"0 jobs near <big town>, England"` for each of them - you're experiencing the same effect.

Comment: May as well upgrade my comment to an answer, since it sort of is.

Comment: Do you want to delete your original comment then?

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has replied to it, doing so would break the conversation thread on the question.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I just got all deja vu when reading the question, then my OCD kicked in.